# Is there a way to cache on load?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there an option with sparksession.read() to cache on load? I'm reading xml files from s3, and it first scans the files to derive a schema. Since it's reading the files anyway, I would rather just load at that time so that it only reads all the files from s3 once.

Is there any way to do this?

I already searched every combination of "spark", "cache", "load", and "read" and went at least two pages deep.

```
sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .load("s3a://<your path here>")
```

Comment: ```val rawData = sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml").load("s3a://").cache()```

The previous line can be used, and remember like RDD, load will be lazily evaluated. So calling load function will not immediately load the data from S3. It will wait until an action is executed in the returned Dataframe `rawData`.

Any consequent transformations that you apply against `rawData` will use the cached `rawData` and will not scan the file again, even if the task failed mid-way and had to restart, the `rawData` will be built according to the lineage (DAG) from the cached version.

Comment: It does read on load, it does it to derive the schema. And even if I do a .cache().count(), it still re-reads the same data set on later steps even though it is completely in memory. Spark is the most frustrating technology I have ever worked with.